# How to extract particular field value from the json api response using fasterxml.jackson

Tags: json, jackson, gson, fasterxml

One of my api response is as below -

```
{
   "statusCode": 422,
   "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
   "message": "Bad data received",
   "err_data": {
       "email": {
           "location": "body",
           "param": "email",
           "value": false,
           "msg": "Please provide valid e-mail address"
       }
   }
}
```

So, in below `response.asString()` represents above response body.

```
ApiResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(response.asString(), ApiResponse.class);
```

`ApiResponse.class` is my model which is as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "statusCode", "message" })
public class ApiResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("statusCode")
    private int statusCode;

    @JsonProperty("err_data")
    private List<String> errData = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private List<String> email = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    private String msg;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     */
    public ApiResponse() {
    }

    /**
     * @param message
     */
    public ApiResponse(int statusCode, String message, List<String> errData, List<String> email, String msg) {
        this.message = message;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.errData = errData;
        this.email = email;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @JsonProperty("statusCode")
    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("statusCode")
    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("err_data")
    public List<String> getErrData() {
        return errData;
    }

    @JsonProperty("err_data")
    public void setErrData(List<String> errData) {
        this.errData = errData;
    }

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public List<String> getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public void setEmail(List<String> email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to get `msg` under `"email":{}`, it is returning `null`.

```
ApiResponse apiResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response.asString(), ApiResponse.class);
// this prints correct value
System.out.println(apiResponse.getMessage()); 

// this prints correct value
System.out.println(apiResponse.getStatusCode());

// this prints empty string array => []
System.out.println(apiResponse.getErrData());

// this also prints empty string array => []
System.out.println(apiResponse.getEmail());

// this prints null
System.out.println(apiResponse.getMsg());
```

I am new to `fasterxml.jackson` lib and not sure what I am missing.

To get `msg` value, what changes I'll have to do in model class above. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where your code is incorrect :

```
@JsonProperty("err_data")
private List<String> errData = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonProperty("email")
private List<String> email = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

Both `email` and `errData` is not a `List`, they are a separate `Object`. Just like the `ApiResponse.java`, you need to create POJO for both objects. For example :

```
public class Email {
     private String location;
     private String param;
     private String value;
     private String msg;
     // define getter and setter
}
```

and

```
public class ErrData {
     private Email email;
     // define getter and setter
}
```

---

Then use the new class as the object type.

```
@JsonProperty("err_data")
private ErrData errData; 
// email is already inside ErrData, you don't need to define them here
```

Finally to access your `msg` :

```
errData.getEmail().getMsg();
```

Hope this is clear enough. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your quick reply!
I did as per your suggestion and then did this to access message but got null pointer.

`ApiResponse apiResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response.asString(), ApiResponse.class);
System.out.println(apiResponse.getErrData().getEmail().getMsg());`

Comment: did you add the @JsonProperty to the email field? you should define them as well on the other classes :D

Comment: I got it now.. field name was different.. I had to rename getter method name  -  `@JsonProperty("err_data")
 public ErrData getErr_data() {
  return err_data;
 }` It is working fine now. `System.out.println(apiResponse.getErr_data().getEmail().getMsg());`